# collapse and expand multiple boxes

Tags: javascript

I'm using below collapse/expand code. it's work, but when I use the code to another text both are expand at the same time. For example, the below "+" icon I clicked on the first one the box expand and in the same time the second box expand without clicking in the icon.

please advise me.

here is the code:

```js
        $(".js-expand").click(function () {
            $(".js-expand").toggleClass('is-expanded');
            $(".figcaption").toggleClass('is-expanded');
        });
```

```css
    
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 330px;
    top: 40%;
}

.figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 1%;
    z-index: 4;
    background: #84BD00 !important;
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width: 220px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

    .figcaption:before {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        bottom: 99.5%;
        left: 0;
        content: '';
        z-index: 3;
        border-left: 15px solid transparent;
        border-right: 15px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 15px solid #84BD00;
        overflow: hidden;
        transform: translateY(100%);
        transition: all 0.75s;
        transition-delay: 0.5s;
    }

    .figcaption.is-expanded {
        top: 50%;
        left: 1%;
        width: 300px;
        max-height: 1000px;
        border-radius: 0;
        max-width: 300px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }

        .figcaption.is-expanded:before {
            left: 30px;
            transform: translateY(0%);
            transition-delay: 0s;
        }

.figcaption-icon {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 1%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 5;
    color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

    .figcaption-icon.is-expanded {
        left: 80%;
        transform: rotate(405deg);
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }

.caption-title {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    background: #323232;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 7.5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transform: translateX(-15px) translateY(10px);
    opacity: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.figcaption.is-expanded .caption-title {
    opacity: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.caption-copy-wrap {
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    background: #84BD00 !important;
    border: none;
}

.figcaption.is-expanded .caption-copy-wrap {
    opacity: 1;
    white-space: normal;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.caption-copy {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 1.28571429;
    text-align: justify;
}


li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
    
    

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Primary Hazards</label>

                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <span class="figcaption-icon js-expand" title="Primary Hazards">&plus;</span>
                            <figcaption class="figcaption">
                                <div class="caption-title">Primary Hazards</div>
                                <div class="caption-copy-wrap">
                                    <div class="form-control" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#txtP4" contenteditable="false" disabled id="txtP4" style="background: #84BD00 !important; border: none;">
                                        <ul class="caption-copy">
                                            <li>Unsafe working area</li>
                                            <li>Personal Injury </li>
                                            <li>Not conducting the joint site inspection </li>
                                            <li>Expire receiver/ issuer certificate </li>
                                            <li>EWrong equipment might be selected </li>
                                            <li>Miss communication </li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </figcaption>
                        </div>




                    </div>
                </div>


            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="bmd-label-floating">Primary Hazards</label>

                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <span class="figcaption-icon js-expand" title="Primary Hazards">&plus;</span>
                        <figcaption class="figcaption">
                            <div class="caption-title">Primary Hazards</div>
                            <div class="caption-copy-wrap">
                                <div class="form-control" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#txtP4" contenteditable="false" disabled id="txtP4" style="background: #84BD00 !important; border: none;">
                                    <ul class="caption-copy">
                                        <li>Unsafe working area</li>
                                        <li>Personal Injury </li>
                                        <li>Not conducting the joint site inspection </li>
                                        <li>Expire receiver/ issuer certificate </li>
                                        <li>EWrong equipment might be selected </li>
                                        <li>Miss communication </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </figcaption>
                    </div>




                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The code can't run because "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the below code for your jquery function

```
$('.js-expand').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('is-expanded')

  });
})
```

Comment: Many thanks, it's work by using each. I was trying using ID, but this much butter. For the plus icon is not rotate after expanded with this code.